# In my macOS App, I get the nasty "Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction" error and a crash, but only when running from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have an Objective-C macOS application that has a window with essentially a `NSTableView` on the left and a details view on the right, in a `NSSplitView`. The window also has labels and other controls. Some of the elements are driven by bindings, some other via referencing outlets. As soon as I open the window, if I don't touch anything, it works. If, as soon as the window opens, I immediately scroll fast with the mouse on any part of the window, I get a crash with this stack trace:

[image]

And the nasty "Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction" error in the log. I know this condition is almost always due to an update to the UI in a background thread, but I am checking my code in countless hours and could not find a single update to the UI done in background. The strangest thing is that the crash only occurs when running the app through Xcode. If I run the app from the Finder it never happens. The NSTableView is driven via datasource and delegate, and I tried to remove the connections and it still happens. I tried to exclude parts of the code with a return statement for example in WindowDidLoad, but it still happens. Also removing the bindings did not solve the situation. Can anybody suggest a powerful technique for finding out the instruction causing the crash?

**Edit:**

I have removed all objects from the window in the `NSWindowController` and left only the `NSScrollView` with the embedded `NSTableView`. It still happens, even if I return manually 0 from `numberOfRowsInTableView`. I have a possible hint that could lead to a solution: If I set the `NSTableView` to not enabled, or hidden, or both, it still happens. If I set the `NSScrollView` to hidden it does not happen any more. I hope this can ring a bell for somebody, as I am really running out of strategies. Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure that all write operations which affect the Key-Value-Observed properties are performed on the main thread.

Comment: I tried to do that and, just to be more sure, I removed all bindings and KVO observed properties, and it still happens. BTW, please tell me if I am wrong, but write operations to KVO observed properties should be done in the main thread only if they affect the UI. In general, write operations to KVO properties that do not affect the UI do not need to be performed on the main thread. Am I wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using an `NSScrollView` & `NSSplitView` to scroll a long view, and I solved this issue by using a subclass of `NSScrollView`. No need to add any code in this subclass. I don't know the reason ,but it works.

Comment: This seems to work for me too. I think Apple might add some asserts or break point to NSScrollView?

Comment: This fixed my issues! Praise the dark lord Coffee.

My situation:
1. Storyboard based UI.
2. Dynamically populated
3. Data refreshes after a network callback, but UI updates happen on main Queue

Comment: Same thing happened here, and using a subclassed-customed NSScrollView worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running some UI updates in Background thread. You can resolve the issue by Properly updating UIs in Main thread instead of background threads.

Identify where it shows the error message, put that inside

`Dispatchqueue.main.async`